# Assign variable value in php

Tags: php

i'm just confused about assigning variable values on php to another one , how does it work?!
 for Example:

```
 <?PHP
    $var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    while($var2=$var1)
     {
       echo $var2[$key];   /** this wont't work Correctly however $var1 it's 
       value = to mysqli_fetch_array**/
     }

    while($var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
     {
      echo $var1[$key];   /** this will work , why ! **/
     }

 ?>
```

Comment: you have a parse error on line 2.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner please could u point to it ?

Comment: The semi-colon is missing for `$var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query)`. That should read as `$var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query);`

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ok fixed but if u know what i mean is to know how assigning in php works?

Comment: Because the second example calls the function for each iteration and thereby exhausts the result set. The first just keep reassigning the first row over and over again.

Comment: @Qirel so it's like first example say ..( hey iam $var1=first row of result has been fetched and this result won't change cause there is no loop to get the second) and second example say ..(iam $var1=result has been fetched each time executing and fetching query till all results finish so $var1=" " ) if u wken what i mean

Comment: I assume when you say "this won't work correctly", you mean to say "this prints only the first result, not all of them as I'd expect" - is that accurate? - Edit: it might actually just hang forever, at second glance.

Comment: @Stratadox Yes exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A peculiarity in PHP's assignment behaviour, is that it also returns the result of the assigned value. This allows for statements such as:

```
$a = $b = $c = 3; // All of a, b and c will equal 3
```

And:

```
while ($variable = call_a_function()) {
  do_something_with($variable);
}
```

In the latter example, `variable` gets assigned to the output of `call_a_function()` at the beginning of the loop iteration; as soon as `call_a_function()` returns a value that evaluates to `false`, the loop ends. If the returned value does not evaluate to `false`, `variable` will contain whatever value was returned, until it gets overwritten again.

Your examples use a similar behaviour. The crucial difference between

```
$var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
while($var2=$var1)
{
  echo $var2[$key];
}
```

And:

```
while($var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $var1[$key];
}
```

...is that in the first example, `$var1` is only assigned to the return value of `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` **before** the loop starts, while in the second example, `$var1` is assigned to the return value of `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` in **every iteration of the loop**.

What makes the two pieces of code crucially different, in the end, is the fact that `mysqli_fetch_array($query)` returns different results, depending on circumstances.

Combining the code snippets into an example that works as intended, yet uses $var2, yields:

```
while($var2=$var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $var2[$key];
}
```

or

```
$var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query); // ask first time
while($var2=$var1)
{
  echo $var2[$key];
  $var1=mysqli_fetch_array($query); // ask again, because the answer changed
}
```

TL;DR: The first example asks a question once, the second asks a question many times. In this case, the intended behaviour of your code requires the question to be asked multiple times, because the answer changes over time.

Comment: Notice that in the end, this was not related to assigning variables per se, but about mysqli_fetch_array not being idempotent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence